# Rails active-record array gives 0 on count but record exists in db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

can anyone help me to solve this mystery?

checkout on image you will understand it

Ruby version - 2.6.0
Rails - 5.2.2

```
(byebug) volume_prices
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Spree::VoumePrice id: 5, variant_id: 4, name: nil, range: "(1..5)", amount: 0.109e3, position: 2, created_at: "2019-05-30 12:49:56", updated_at: "2019-05-30 12:49:56", discount_type: "price", role_id: nil, volume_price_model_id: nil, user_id: nil, supplier_id: 3, pricing_tier_id: 5>]>
(byebug) volume_prices.count
0
(byebug) volume_prices.length
1
(byebug) Spree::VolumePrice.find(5)
#<Spree::VolumePrice id: 5, variant_id: 4, name: nil, range: "(1..5)", amount: 0.1e2, position: 1, created_at: "2019-05-30 12:54:00", updated_at: "2019-05-30 12:54:00", discount_type: "price", role_id: nil, volume_price_model_id: nil, user_id: nil, supplier_id: 4, pricing_tier_id: 5>
```

Comment: Would you please replace the picture with properly-formatted text (copied from your console)? Pictures can be difficult to view on some devices and make it impossible to copy and paste for answers.

Comment: What is `volume_prices`? Where do you define it?

Comment: @Vasilisa it is just a local variable and assiged with  active record query result

Comment: @VishalG could you please add the query to the question?

Answer (score 1):

`volume_prices` is NOT an array, it is an `AcitveRecord::Relation`, so that may have something to do with it. I would recommend using `#size` instead of `#length` or `#count`. `#size` will always give you the number you're looking for, regardless of if it's an array or a `Relation`.

If it's a relation, it will run the SQL command for counting instead of querying for all records and THEN counting in Ruby.

```
[1] pry(main)> User.all.size
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`
=> 10
[2] pry(main)> User.all.to_a.size
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
=> 10
[3] pry(main)> User.all.length
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
=> 10
```

Comment: Offcouse we can do that, my question was why it is happening  with count

Comment: I think that in OP case, `size` will return the same as `length` because it will check if the relation is loaded. For more details, check my response

Answer (score 1):

An `ActiveRecord::Relation` can be loaded in memory. When a relation is loaded, you can work on it without hitting the database with queries.

The mystery in your case is that `volume_prices` is a relation that has been loaded in memory, so `.length` method will not perform any query on the database. However, `.count` will perform a query, because [it is a calculation method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/06ae49d99c4bc6263a913529ca969d5505fcfdbe/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb#L41) of `ActiveRecord`.

I think that the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/06ae49d99c4bc6263a913529ca969d5505fcfdbe/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L261) of `Activerecord` `size` method is the perfect example of this approach, because it checks if the relation is loaded before decide which method will use between `count` and `length`.

You can check all of this by running this lines in your very example:

```
volume_prices.loaded?       # should return true
volume_prices.count         # should return 0
volume_prices.length        # should return 1
volume_prices.reload.length # should return 0
```